# Gradient of a function while using the method of images in electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, dipole

I was solving a physics problem (to be more specific I was trying to find the image of a dipole by a grounded sphere) when I came across \begin{equation} \mathbf{\nabla}_{\mathbf{d}} \left( \frac{1}{\left| \mathbf{r}-\frac{a^2}{\left| \mathbf{r}' + \mathbf{d} \right|^2} \left( \mathbf{r}' + \mathbf{d} \right) \right|} \right). \end{equation} Now, I know that \begin{equation} \mathbf{\nabla}_{\mathbf{d}} \left( \frac{1}{\mathbf{r}'+\mathbf{d}} \right) = - \frac{\mathbf{r}'+\mathbf{d}}{\left| \mathbf{r}'+\mathbf{d} \right|^3}, \end{equation} but the first gradient remains a mystery to me. Does anyone know how to solve it? Maybe there is a property of the composition of functions that can help, but I haven't found anything so far.

Going back to the problem I was trying to solve, my professor suggested another way to obtain the solution and it worked magic, so the problem is already solved. I just wanted to know how to deal with the gradient. Thank you very much and sorry for my english (it isn't my first language).

Comment: In the worst case you can always express the expression in brackets in terms of the components of $r$ and $d$, so that you have a function of many variables $f(r_1, r_2, r_3, d_1, d_2, d_3)$ if you are working in three dimensions. Then the three components of the gradient are just the derivatives of this function w.r.t. $d_1, d_2$ and $d_3$ respectively.

Comment: Yes, that idea had crossed my mind, haven't really tried it though. I thought maybe I could find a way to operate directly on the vectors. Thanks @DelCrosB!